# Why Doesn't "if" without "else" work in this case?

Tags: r, shiny

I figured out a problem I was having, but I would like to learn why my original script didn't work.

Let's say I want a radio button to choose between two tables. This is a MRE of what I tried:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons(inputId = "in.or.out",
                         label = "choose one",
                         choices = c("Inside"=1,"Outside"=2))
            
        ),

        mainPanel(
           dataTableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

    table.out<-reactive({
        in.or.out<-input$in.or.out
        if(in.or.out==1){
            data<-c(4,3,2,1)
            label<-c("This","is","selected","one")
            final.table<-data.frame(label,data)
            
        }
        if(in.or.out==2){
            data<-c(1,2,3,4)
            label<-c("This","is","selected","two")
            final.table<-data.frame(label,data)
        }
    })
    
    output$table<-renderDataTable({
        table.out()
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The solution is to add an "else" after the first if statement closes. I get why that works, but based on the flowchart of "if" I would have expected it to work without an else. Kind of like, "if it equals 1, do this. If it equals 2 do that" instead of "if it equals 1 to this, else if it equals 2 do that."

I feel I am missing something very basic here, and I had better learn it!

Comment: You're reactive object needs to return a value.  By default a block will return the last expression evaluated. If an `if()` statement is FALSE and it doesn't have an `else`, that `if` block will return `NULL`. What are you trying to return from `table.out`? Just the value of `final.table`? You can include that at the end of the reactive block. Then it would work just fine. But the values for `data` and `label` will be lost since you can only return one "thing" as your reactive expression (though that "thing" could be a list which contains multiple values)

Comment: Oooh, I think I understand. I was returning the final table within the if statement, so if in.or.out == 1 it does everything fine, but then it evaluates the second if and comes back NULL. Thanks, that saves future errors!